# Question deleted but not off-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, specific-question, deleted-questions

From my point of view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193023/) should not have been deleted.

It is a programming related question.

Maybe a very easy one, but I think many could benefit from the answer given.

Sure it should get reworded, what I was about to do, till it got closed.

Comment: "How do I use my keyboard?" is a programming question now?

Comment: @animuson maybe superuser?  ;P

Comment: @animuson from my point of view, yes, for that special case, hence you dont need the | usually?

Comment: I don't use the `^` symbol much either. Does that mean I can ask how to type it on Mathematics?

Comment: @animuson I´m about to say yes, since it´s something related to a specific field (in ure example mathematics, Physics)

Comment: @animuson If you actually have a genuine problem typing it, then yeah, why not.  We allow questions about how to use your IDE, why not this?

Comment: @animuson and if the OP's keyboard is foreign or somehow broken or misconfiguration or something like that, it's a perfectly valid question he asked.

Comment: @animuson or never learned about Computers in school and want to teach himself coding and for him its very hard to figure it out so he tried to describe it.

Comment: You guys can argue about it all you want. This question is terrible and does not belong here, and it won't be undeleted.

Comment: @bluefeet ,animuson then, seriously remove **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**  from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you read carefully, the phrase **"and is"** precedes that one.  Your question still has to be categorically on-topic under one of the other bullets.

Comment: @Felix: how are keyboards *unique to software development*?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters how is polymorphism unique to software delopment?

Comment: I feel like I'm playing a basketball game where the rules are constantly changing.  "That basket doesn't count.  You were supposed to put it in your own basket that time, cuz I sez so.  That's a foul!  you didn't say 'Simon Says' first."

Comment: Possible relevant in-so-far as it shapes the reaction of old hands like me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19487#19487.

Comment: @dmckee sheesh, the link is http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19487/1228 Now if you will excuse me, I have to ask on SO how to waterproof my catamaran, I've lost yet another development laptop to the bilge!

Answer (score 27):

That question was becoming a magnet for all kinds of badness, so since it was already well on its way to getting closed, I gave it the heave ho.

- 5 moderator flags on the question
- 7 moderator flags on one of the answers
- 14 total downvotes
- 5 moderator-deleted comments

**Verdict:** Nuke from orbit.

For what it's worth, this user has a history of extremely basic questions, including a deleted "how do I get started in Java" question with 10 downvotes.  This kind of thing is not really what we're here for.

Comment: @mods Ure job is it not to act like kids, (moderators making fun of users in !Public COMMENTS! who are not good in something is a NOGO)  but ok hey keep wondering why there are so many low posts, if you rather delete, than edit the ones with a good answer which guides new Programmers. In the future I wont even try to answer on a newbie Question..... Im so sorry, how did I even dare to do so

Comment: Thos dam modraters.  Their just monkeys with guns in there hands. How dare them for wanting to preserv sum qualitee.

Comment: not saying that, but making fun of users in public commentaries is something what a mod shouldnt do.

Comment: Which is why I shut down the question.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: so you shot down the question cuz an other moderator made fun of him, other users joined, like hey if a mod does that, then im allowed to do so aswell? GOOOOD JOB. Congratulations

Comment: Perhaps you would find Yahoo Answers a more welcoming environment.

Comment: I reviewed the question again.  There's not a single comment there written by a moderator, so I don't know what you're on about.

Comment: you mean theres - not anymore - a single comment there written by a moderator nevermind I am out. Nonsense discussing this with petty people.

Comment: @FelixLahmer we're actually pretty fair and even-handed around here, though moderators are still human and do (occasionally) make mistakes, but those always end up being corrected. "Petty" we are certainly not. Well, *most* of us anyways.

Comment: To be clear, moderators can see the entire comment history of a post, including the deleted comments.  There's not a single diamond anywhere in the written comments, past or present.

Answer (score -14):

you can find information on what is topical [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

That being said...

- You were asking a question about a "tool commonly used by programmers", the keyboard.
- You needed an answer for the purpose of programming.
- Since not everyone on Earth uses the same kind of keyboard, It's reasonable to assume that you work with a keyboard that doesn't have a `shift` key,
- It's not unreasonable that your keyboard might be broken or mapped in an odd way.
- Even if shift would work, It's also reasonable to assume that you legitimately aren't use to using the shift button, just the same as the vast majority of askers aren't particularly familiar with what they're asking about, and I can't imagine how I would search for how to use the shift key if i didn't already know about the shift key.

I think that it was a valid question, and frankly, the moderator was out of line for deleting it.

Comment: Your first bullet point is incorrect. The help center does explicitly include the word "software" before the word "tools"... As far as I know, a keyboard is hardware, not software.

Comment: Toothbrushes are a tool commonly used by programmers too, but that doesn't mean that questions about toothbrushes are automatically on-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey At least I *hope* the toothbrush is commonly used by programmers..